# Still cannot use `react-native link` after ejecting a Create React Native App

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app, create-react-app

I started with a create-react-native app. Then, I wanted to add a dependency. So, I ran `react-native link`:

```
`react-native link` can not be used in Create React Native App projects. If you need to include a library that relies on custom native code, you might have to eject first. See https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md for more information.
```

So, I ran `npm run eject` and it successfully ejected. There are many changes to the `package.json` and some scripts have been added.

But, if I now run `react-native link`, I still get the same error!! How can I successfully run this command? How does it determine that I'm still using create-react-native?

I'm guessing there's some flag somewhere that still says it's using create-react-native, but I don't know where it is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
react-native link
```

only works when you have added any new package eg:- `npm i react-native-vector-icons`. then you need to import package name to various class manually but if you dont want to do it you can directly run the command 
`react-native link react-native-vector-icons` OR `react-native link`

this will automatically add import the package to your ios and android files.
Try these steps it will work.